# How to generate a random float in range [-1,1] using numpy.random.rand()?

Tags: python, numpy, random

Numpy's random.rand() function produces random floats between 0 and 1. How do I transform the output of this function to produce random floats between -1 and 1?

Current output:

```
In[]: numpy.random.rand(3, 2)
Out[]: 
array([[0.13568674, 0.72465483],
       [0.48726461, 0.68867378],
       [0.50463821, 0.28619853]])
```

Desired (example) output:

```
In[]: numpy.random.rand(3, 2)
Out[]: 
array([[-0.13568674, 0.72465483],
       [-0.48726461, 0.68867378],
       [0.50463821, -0.28619853]])
```

I would **not** like to use random.uniform().

Comment: `(numpy.random.rand(3, 2) - 0.5) * 2`

Comment: What's the reason not to use `np.random.uniform`? That's an odd restriction; do you have a good reason for avoiding it, and are there other, similar restrictions? You seem be operating under an unusual set of constraints, and it would be useful to know what those are.

Answer (score 3):

You basically need to scale and shift the `(0, 1)` range normally generated by `np.random.rand()` to the `(-1, 1)` target range:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
max_val, min_val = 1, -1
range_size = (max_val - min_val)  # 2
np.random.rand(N) * range_size + min_val
```

or other equivalent algebra.

---

Alternatively, you could use `np.random.randint()` to generate a `int` range to be divided by (a fraction of) its size.

For your specific range, this would look like:

```
import numpy as np


N = 10
L = 100
np.random.randint(-L, L, N) / L
```

This would be (slightly) slower than the `np.random.random()` approach, but would give you control over the "density" of the result.

---

(EDITED: explicitly write the relationship between the algebra and the target range)

Comment: The second option will create a more stratified or binned random sampling, since there are only `200/10 = 20` possible values now. This gives the control over density. However, this may or may not be applicable to the specific use-case. The best thing, perhaps is to apply `np.random.rand` and then use some form of binning if necessary. But yes, both methods could be applicable ways of sampling in some scenarios. If someone is blindly applying uniform random sampling, I would suggest to use the first method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a random float between two values `a` and `b`, where `a < b`, then it is done as follows. This is equivalent to redistributing or **re-scaling** the random-distribution between `[0,1]` to the desired interval `[a,b]` (equivalent to stretching or compressing, depending on whether `(b - a)` is `<`, `=` or `>` `(1 - 0)`.

```py
import numpy as np
# in your case:
a, b = -1, 1
(b - a)*np.random.rand() + a
```

Comment: This is correct, are the same instructions provided in the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.random.html). Quote: `(...). To sample Unif[a, b), b > a multiply the output of random by (b-a) and add a. (...)`